# CloudWatch / Autoscaling - Remove Capacity Metric Alarm always shows in Alarm, how can I make it not

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

using the example from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html I created an alarm to trigger pruning any unused auto-scaled instances.

I'm a big fan of not having angry red items on a page when there isn't anything to do as it desensitizes you to when there is an actual error.

I know that I can click Hide Auto Scaling alarms and all of them will go away but I would rather see them.

Is there any option or is this just how it is.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As long as the CPU usage stays low (under 40% average for the ASG), that alarm will stay in that state.  This means that technically that alarm is doing something.  Every minute that it stays in the Alarm state its sending a notification to AutoScaling with the current metric values.  I assume the group has already scaled in to the minimum size, and is therefore ignoring those notifications, but they are still happening.

In general, you want the AutoScaling aspects to be hands off and more or less 'set it and forget it' kinds of things, so hiding AutoScaling alarms might be your best bet.